# How do I send inputs as well as xml to a url for response?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, http, post

Unfortunately I can't share public details of the service (and even if I, it is very little known, so doesn't matter).

I am getting a problem with sending xml data along with input fields over http ? I guess this is a noob question, but I am really not able to figure out.

There is an xml with fields and there are input fields which I have to send over http. Here are input fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="RESPONSE_URL"
        value="http://XXXX/" />
 <input type="hidden"
        name="PARTNER_CODE" value="TRTRTRABTEST" />
 <input type="hidden"
name="QUOTE_ID" value="123456789012345" />
```

Any pointer to a tutorial along with your negative vote will be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

//Your XML data in a string

```
<FORM action="PAGE YOU WANT TO SEND DATA" method="post">
    <P>
  <input type="hidden" name="RESPONSE_URL"
    value="http://XXXX/" />
   <input type="hidden"
    name="xml_data" value="<?php echo $xml_data; ?>" />
   <input type="hidden"
       name="QUOTE_ID" value="123456789012345" /> 
    <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
    </P>
 </FORM>
```

You need to ***post*** the data.

Check out http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_method.asp

Comment: i want to send xml as well along with this data

Comment: is it the only way to do it ? If so, I am getting error on this. Is there any way possible using curl ?

Comment: Yes, you could post a link to a page, then curl that page from your receiving code. There are many ways to do this.